# While creating a random forest using foreach() in R, I am getting error, cannot find randomForest() function

Tags: r, foreach, random-forest, doparallel

While trying to perform parallel processing in R for creating random forests of 51 trees using 3 cores, I am getting error 
**"Error in randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "randomForest""**

Please help. The code I used is below:

```
library(doParallel)
library(randomForest)
cl<-makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
cl
attach(train)
x<-train[,2:94]
y<-train$target
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(17, 3), .combine=combine) %dopar% randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
```

Comment: `foreach(ntree=rep(17, 3), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest')`

Comment: try using the `caret` package it performs randomforest analysis but does so with all your cores without you fiddling with it yourself.